# Why does event listener callback function only work inside function scope?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a D3 project that uses an event listener which gets called every few milliseconds to update/animate the position of circles on the screen.

It starts with the function startForces() getting called once to activate the D3 forces and we pass it the circles.

When the callback function (ticked) is positioned outside of the scope of startForces(), the function only seems to called once and the circles appear static on the page. (SEE TOP CODE CHUNK)

But, when the callback function (ticked) is positioned inside the scope of startForces(), everything works as expected and the circles appear animated. (BOTTOM CODE CHUNK)

I'm trying to understand why javascript is working this way. Why does the top code not work, and the bottom code work?

## TL:DR

## NOT-WORKING CODE

```
var ticked = function(circles){
   circles.attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x })
   .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y })
}

var startForces = function(data, circles) {
  simulation.nodes(data)
  .on('tick', ticked(circles))
}
```

=====

## WORKING CODE

```
    var startForces = function(data, circles) {
      simulation.nodes(data)
      .on('tick', ticked)

    function ticked(){
      circles.attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x })
      .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y })
    }
   }
```

Why the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually has nothing to do with the position of the functions at all.

When you do this:

`.on('tick', ticked(circles))`

You immediately call `ticked` right as you create the `on` listener. Then, you assign the callback for `tick` to be the *result* of calling `ticked` with circles, which is `undefined`.

When you do this:

`.on('tick', ticked)`

You assign the callback to be the `ticked` function, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Wrapping my head around it but it's starting to make sense.

Comment: Yeah, this trips a lot of people up! Just remember that the evaluated value of `ticked(circles)` is undefined, but the value of `ticked` is the function itself.  You want to assign the function to the callback, not its return value.

Comment: @Starcat Just to add my two cents to thedayturns' answer: normally, a `tick` function in the force simulation doesn't need arguments. However, if you do need, for some reason, pass any argument to it, wrap it in an anonymous function: `on('tick', function(){ ticked(foo)})`.